# Is this the best way to fight "The War On Christmas"?

Tags: saint, christmas

From [here](https://archive.ph/ihvxp):

> Happy St. Francis Day! (Oh, And Also Yom Kippur)

> It has become a multicultural must to step on Christmas by never mentioning it except in connection with Hanukkah and other “holidays.“ Somehow, however, the MSM neglects to provide the nearest Saint’s day in the Christian calendar to each year’s Rosh Hashanah, Yom Kippur and Passover—there are a lot of saints! So it has become a VDARE.com service (as so often) to fill the gap. We wish a Happy to all our readers. We mean it.

He does something similiar [here](https://archive.ph/1MAyh) & [here](https://archive.ph/kRdO7). Thing is that venerating saints like this is only a Catholic thing correct? Isn't this stepping on the beliefs of other denominations that don't venerate the saints through holidays or the like?

Comment: Why should Christians be involved in a "war" on Christmas at all?!

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work with Protestantism. Venerating Saints is done by both the Catholic and Orthodox branches of Christianity, so most Christians, although these have different Saints on a given day (and some of their Saints don't overlap). For ex., you can see the Orthodox calendar here https://www.allsaintsnc.org/orthodox-saints-calendar/

Comment: Yom Kippur's date varies, but there isn't a major Christian calendar event that is across Catholicism and Protestantism that I can think of that is close to it. All Saints' Day is perhaps the closest that is observed within Catholicism and some Protestant denominations.

Comment: I leaning towards an opinion based question. ***Is this the best way to fight* "The War On Christmas"?** It does seem opinion based to me?

Answer (score 2):

Is this the best way to fight the war on Christmas?

Definitely not.

A much better way would be to point out that:

- Most Christmas traditions originated from pagan mythology (tree, yule log).
- Newer Christmas traditions were created by secular organizations for advertising purposes (e.g. Rudolph, Santa Claus).
- The Bible explicitly condemns following non-biblical practices ("Learn not the way of the heathen").

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Catholic, there's no reason not to wish people a happy Saint day.  Bringing in some traditional goodies from a particular feast (I'm sure you can find this on a site like [Catholic Icing](https://www.catholicicing.com/category/liturgical-year/)) is a great way.  I know
Jews who are apt to do this for their feasts and turnabout is fairplay and usually tasty and even secular culture sees this as a good and normal thing.

Showing your neighbors and coworkers that there is such a thing as Catholic Culture isn't a bad thing, thousands of traditions have been lost to secularism and most of our feasts are secular feasts today.

Remembering saints isn't even necessarily about their veneration, although that's an important component if you're praying the liturgy of the hours or going to Mass for a particular saint's feast or commemoration.

Also many saints are still remembered on Anglican and Lutheran liturgical calendars,  a few saints overlap between Orthodox and Catholic calendars, but their "days" often do not.

Also, there's no reason for Catholics not to enjoy Jewish feast days, Jesus didn't come into the world to abolish feasting!

Christmas will always need to be defended since the devil clearly hates it.  Getting back to having a culture that knows how to feast is the only way to get to a culture that can celebrate its principal feasts.